# Not able to apply angular js built in filter for date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angularjs-filter

My scope variable is holding a date in this format:

```
$scope.thisDay="2016-01-01 00:00:01"

{{thisDay}} --->2016-01-01 00:00:01
```

I applied a date filter for the above like:

```
{{thisDay | date:'medium'}}
```

But this dosen't seem to be working in my case.
Any suggestions regarding the above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`Date`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)** filter need date type data but you are providing string instead of date.

Try like this

```
$scope.thisDay=new Date("2016-01-01 00:00:01");
```

<kbd>**[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/2e26tofu/2/)**</kbd>

If you don't wanna to convert date in scope

Then create a filter which will convert your string to date object

```
myApp.filter('convert2date', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input ? new Date(input) : "";
  };
});
```

Add it your html

```
 {{thisDay | convert2date |date:'medium'}}
```

<kbd>**[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/d1dh4u88/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: I want to make the change directly in the html

Comment: I'm gettingn null in the fiddle result

Answer (score 0):

According to [Date filter documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), the `date` argument should be:

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number)
>   or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g.
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is
>   specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the
>   local timezone.

So, you need to convert your string into a valid javascript date, perhaps create your own filter that depend on angularjs built-in date filter

```
angular.module('app').filter('customDateFormat', function($filter) {
    return function(value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return $filter('date')(new Date(value).toISOString(), 'medium');
    };
});
```

Then in your html,
`{{ thisDay | customDateFormat}}`

***Update:***

Furthermore, what if you want to make your filter more generic and pass the date format along with your date:

```
angular.module('app').filter('customDate', function($filter) {
    return function(value, format, defaultValue) {
        if (value == null) {
            if (defaultValue) {
                return defaultValue;
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return $filter('date')(new Date(value).toISOString(), format);
    };
});
```

Then in your HTML:

```
{{thisDay | customDateFormat:'shortTime'}}
```